# Can I use triangle list from RVIZ to display a polygon mesh from PCL?

Tags: rviz, pcl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to display a polygon mesh in real time in rviz. I am using the mesh from pcl (pcl::PolygonMesh).
I believe that the only way is to use the triangle list method but I cant seem to get it to work.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279982/can-i-use-triangle-list-from-rviz-to-display-a-polygon-mesh-from-pcl?/) by [simaopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32526/simaopp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way of doing this is to publish the mesh using the a marker message containing a triangle list. There's an example of this in the [documentation here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker). You may need to write your own code to convert from the pcl type to the maker message. This should be fairly straightforward though, you build a list of vertices and a list of colors, each triangle contributes 3 vertices and 1 color to these lists.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simaopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32526/simaopp/) on 2018-01-16**:
Should I use the geometry_msgs::Point to build the vertices list?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
Be aware of the various issues with `_LIST` markers. See the [rviz issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues) (search for `triangle` or `list`).